# Releasing parts of a multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

Assume I have a multi-module project with three modules A, B, C where A depends on B and B depends on C.

Assume now I make a change in B. Then I would like to release new versions of B and A. Releasing C would be strange because it did not change nor did any of its dependencies. So B could still depend on the last release version of C.

How would I handle this? Or is my logic flawed and I should always release all modules?

Comment: I would make a release of all modules to make sure everything is in line and is easier to understand from users point of view. Otherwise you should think about moving away from a multi module build...

Comment: I understand that having a common version number for all modules and building them all at once is probably the easiest way to handle multi-module projects. And it is good to have your opinion on that because you are so much more experienced than I am. But still I wonder if it is right to change the version number of _every_ module if you change something at just one point. Of course, this depends on the size of the multi-module-project, if it is 5 or 50 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed - C does not need to be updated.

If the **interface** of B did not change, then an update to A is not required.

Conversely, if the **interface** of B did change, then A must be updated at the same time as B. However, sometimes it makes sense/less risk to maintain backwards compatibility by keeping the old B interface along with adding the new interface.  Then add a technical debt item against A to get A updated at some future point to use the new interface of B, and remove the old interface of B.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer does not address how one should handle this issue in the context of Maven multi-module projects.

Comment: Furthermore, I disagree that an update of A is not necessary. Users of A want to have the newest dependency when they depend on A.

Comment: Can you be specific about how my answer does not address your question?

Comment: Why would A need to be updated if nothing changed in A, along with the interface to B remaining the same.? For example, service A invokes service B.  The internals of B might have changed, but why would A care about that?

Comment: Do you mean B is packaged as a jar, and included in A?  Then yes, a new version of A would be needed.

Comment: B can be included in A, but this is not necessary. The dependencies I mention are Maven dependencies. If you do not change A, it will still have the old version of B as dependency, no matter what you do to B (we are talking about artifacts, not REST services).

Comment: And my question is about handling the situation in Maven multi module projects. You did not mention any Maven goal or Maven plugin in your answer.